# Elastic X axis for stacked barchart, removing the empty bins [dc.js]

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

There is this [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filtering-removing.html) that shows how you can make an elastic X axis that removes the empty bins using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) and the chart.elasticX(true) method.

I'm trying to make this work with a stacked barchart but I face a problem. I have slightly modified the code of the above example to use a stacked group for the barchart. (I have added an Earned column in the data, made a fake group for it and assigned it to the chart.stack method). But for certain "Earned" values there is a d3.js error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.**

#### #

**Update**:
This issue is related with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361056/2369865) which states that "The stack method expects your data to be equally length-ed". It is also related with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899172/2369865) that proposes the creation of a combined group to overcome the problem.

#### #

Here is the modified example code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Filtering Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0/dc.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js"></script>
  <p>Example demonstrating using a "<a href="https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups">Fake Group</a>" to remove
    the empty bars of an ordinal bar chart when their values drop to zero.</p>

  <p>(Note the use of <code><a href="https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+elasticX">.elasticX(true)</a></code>
    to force calculation of the X domain each round.)</p>

<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0/dc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
    spendHistChart  = dc.barChart("#chart-hist-spend"),
    spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");
// use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv", function(error, spendData) {/* do stuff */});
var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Earned: '$70', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Earned: '$20', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Earned: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Earned: '$170', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Earned: '$30', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Earned: '$30', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Earned: '$70', Year: 2013}
];
// normalize/parse data
spendData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
    d.Earned = d.Earned.match(/\d+/);
});
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
// set crossfilter
var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    earnDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Earned/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount(),
    earnHist    = earnDim.group().reduceCount(),
    nonEmptyHist = remove_empty_bins(spendHist)
    nonEmptyEarnHist = remove_empty_bins(earnHist)

yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);

spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .stack(nonEmptyEarnHist)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);
spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

spenderRowChart
    .width(350).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);

dc.renderAll();
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However if you change the Earned values to

```
var spendData = [
        {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Earned: '$70', Year: 2011},
        {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Earned: '$20', Year: 2011},
        {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Earned: '$40', Year: 2011},
        {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Earned: '$170', Year: 2012},
        {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Earned: '$30', Year: 2012},
        {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Earned: '$50', Year: 2013},  // This is the only change Earned from '$30' to '$50'
        {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Earned: '$70', Year: 2013}
    ]
```

Then it works fine.

I face the same d3 error for my case so I tried to reproduce it with a simple example.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042138/dc-js-d3-js-how-to-hide-a-bar-chart-x-axis-category-value-if-its-bar-value-e) related question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, [you found the answer already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886088/dc-js-stacked-bar-chart-with-empty-bin-filter-displaying-in-strange-way/30899172#30899172); it's just a matter of applying it.

This is indeed the same question that can be solved with a combined group.

```
combinedGroup = combine_groups(nonEmptyHist,nonEmptyEarnHist)

function sel_stack(i) {
    return function(d) {
        return d.value[i];
    };
}

spendHistChart
    .group(combinedGroup, 'spend', sel_stack(0))
    .stack(combinedGroup, 'earn', sel_stack(1))
```

I don't know of another way to deal with this; `d3.stack` requires arrays of the same size and dc.js will also assume that the key/value arrays correspond to each other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/dwkgud92/3/

Comment: Indeed. I had another issue that caused this method to fail but now everything works as expected. The issue was that the combined group keys are strings and so they are not ordered correctly in charts. In your fiddle notice the histogram x axis order: 10 170 20 30 ... You have to convert the keys to integers (in this case) in order to be ordered correctly. in combine_groups function: ret.push({key: **parseInt(k)**, value: gm[**parseInt(k)**]}); Thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip! I'll try to generalize that function. Glad it works!

Comment: A quick solution would be to patch the combine_groups.all method when you want to use it and modify the type of keys there. In case of integers:                                                              `var original_method = combined_group.all;
        combined_group.all = function(){
            var res = original_method.apply(this, arguments);
            for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
                res[i].key = parseInt(res[i].key)
            }
            return res
        };`